# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type CdiCamelExtension with qualifiers @Default

Tags: apache-camel, cdi, jboss-eap-7, apache-camel-cdi

We are migrating from EAP 6 to EAP 7 one project that uses  Apache Camel. In this project, we are using dependency injection using the CDI 2.0 specification provided by EAP 7. We are migrating from EAP 6.4 which is using CDI 1.X specification. The Apache Camel version that we are using is 2.17.6

We have updated our project with the appropiate changes in the code, but in the moment of deploying the application in the server, we are getting this error, coming from the Camel dependency:

```
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type CdiCamelExtension with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 3 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces private static org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelFactory.typeConverter(InjectionPoint, @Any Instance<CamelContext>, CdiCamelExtension)
  at org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelFactory.typeConverter(CdiCamelFactory.java:0)
```

It seems that it is a problem related with Apache Camel, with the 3rd parameter of the signature, that cannot find the way to obtain an object to inject it here.

The camel library camel-cdi-2.17.6jar file that contains the class org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelExtension, and the service configuration in this jar is indicating to use this CdiCamelExtension.

We can see also that within this library the beans.xml file contains:

```
<beans version="1.0" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <scan>
        <exclude name="org.apache.camel.cdi.Main"/>
    </scan>
</beans>
```

With all this, we cannot see why CdiCamelContext cannot be obtained.

Could this be because EAP 7 is using CDI 2.0, and Camel 2.17.6 could not be compatible with this specification? We don't have much experience with Camel, so we are not sure if we could be missing something with it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you managed to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

adding `<module name="org.apache.camel" annotations="true" meta-inf="true"/>` to global-modules of standalone.xml worked for me.